# best practice to save temporary data from a form in case of PC shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I've created a C# forms application in which the user must enter production data of that working day.
Now I was thinking that in case of a sudden shutdown of the PC, the operator will have lost all the production data that was already filled in that day.
So when he restarts the application all the data should have to be filled in again.
At the end of the day (production order ends) all this data may be deleted again.

I was thinking of putting everything in a sql database and then delete it again at the end of the day, but this seems a bit of overkill.

Most of the production data will be entered in textboxes and datagridviews.

What would be an easier solution for this?

Comment: Mentioning "Most of the production data will be entered in textboxes and datagridviews." sometimes indicates a poor separation between UI and data structures. Is it so?

Comment: Why do you think putting it in a database is overkill? I don't understand the need for deleting at the end of day. As a database you could simply use LiteDb. It is embedded and you could delete as you see fit (https://www.litedb.org/)

Comment: Why don't you want to use a database? There’s not too many other ways of doing it.

Comment: If it's just store and load objects again I would tend to use JSON and save it to a file.

Comment: Easy is relative, either serialize the data to file (regularly), or update a database. both are fairly easily. This is your mission, if you choose to accept it

Answer (score -1):

I wrote some POS app in nigera before, works fine with their local unstable environment (power shortage).

maybe you should give it a try, it took me one month to implement it on my software.

[Microsoft Sync Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework)